# Image reading in FPGA

Tags: fpga, matlab, imageprocessing

I'm a newbie to FPGA stuffs and I'm using Zybo board.I need to read image stored in a hex file by FPGA and save the processed result in a hex file again.
How can I implement this?
How can I connect Zybo board through MATLAB?

Comment: This is quite a huge question, whose answer would need something around the size of a book. If you are a newbie, you have a long way to walk with many intermediate steps before you reach the image processing stage

Answer (score 1):

To set ut your board follow this guide to get started [MathWorks - Set up the ZYBO board](https://se.mathworks.com/help/hdlcoder/examples/define-and-register-custom-board-and-reference-design-for-soc-workflow.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com).
For the rest of your question I have to repeat what Claudio wrote, what you want is quite a ways off if you don't know any HDL.